GLSL Clamp function not working as expected (Minecraft Shaders)
In my Minecraft shader, this line of code is not working as expected:
finalDayColor = mix(vec3(1.00, 0.37, 0.00), vec3(1.00, 0.92, 0.82), clamp(worldTime, 0.0, 1.0));

The variable worldTime is a uniform integer, and finalDayColor is a vec3. The code is compiling with no errors.
What I expected was that finalDayColor would return a color based on the worldTime. Instead, it would return the same color, not depending on worldTime. I think this is because the clamp function is returning something else.
I tried messing around with the values and finding alternative functions but to no avail. Is there anything I am doing wrong?
EDIT: Thanks for the community for responding to my question. It is now solved.

By the way, you may want to improve this question by adding the GLSL version and what values for worldTime you have tested this with. Even better, include more context: create a [mre] for this shader and at least describe the context in which it is used.

Let's start with the basics: you wrote that worldTime is an integer, meaning it can't store fractional numbers. So the value can be -1, 0, 1, 2, etc., but not 0.5.
The function clamp doesn't have a signature with the parameters int, float, float, but (desktop) GLSL can convert ints to floats (implicit conversion). So while worldTime is an int, it'll be converted to a float. floats can store fractional numbers, but since it was converted from an int, the fractional part will always be 0.
The clamp function has 3 parameters: x, minVal, and maxVal. It returns x if it's between minVal and maxVal. It returns minVal, if x is lower than minVal, and returns maxVal, if x is greater than maxVal. So essentially the returned value will always be between minVal, and maxVal. Based on your arguments, the returned value is 0.0, if wordTime is lower or equal to 0.0, and it returns 1.0, if wordTime is greater or equal to 1.0. I'm not sure what you store in wordTime, but I imagine something that increases every frame, or every second, which means that clamp will almost always return 1.0.
The mix function mixes (linearly interpolates) the 2 vectors, based on the 3rd argument (the clamp function call). So if clamp returns 0.0, mix will return vec3(1.00, 0.37, 0.00), if clamp returns 1.0, mix will return vec3(1.00, 0.92, 0.82). If clamp returns 0.5, mix will return a vector halfway between these vectors. However, as I mentioned earlier, in this case, clamp won't return 0.5, only either 0.0, or 1.0. So the result will be one of the 2 vectors, most likely the 2nd.
So technically finalDayColor depends on wordTime, but you manipulate it so that you won't see a gradual change between the 2 vectors (which I assume is your goal). If you want gradual change, I'd do something like this:
finalDayColor = mix(vec3(1.00, 0.37, 0.00), vec3(1.00, 0.92, 0.82), sin(time) * 0.5 + 0.5);

Where time is a uniform float variable that contains the elapsed time since you started the application or something like that. The sin function returns a value between -1.0 and 1.0. Then I multiply it by 0.5, so the interval will be between -0.5 and 0.5 and then add 0.5, so the final interval will be between 0.0 and 1.0, so you don't even need the clamp.

Yes, worldTime can be converted to a float, but it still may not compile depending on the exact OpenGL version and GPU. Nvidia will report an ambiguous overloaded function, considering the types lowp float, mediump float, and superp float, and float.

All desktop GLSL versions support int -> float conversions, except version 110. None of GLSL ES versions support any implicit conversions. So 5 GLSL versions don't support this conversion, but in that case, it's a compile-time error, he said that it compiled without errors (compiles with glslang too). It seems that Nvidia doesn't follow the specification, which says: "Similarly, precision qualifiers, as with other qualifiers, do not contribute to function overloading based on parameter types." But the easiest way is to declare the uniform variable as float, or use the float constructor.

I agree, and Nvidia indeed appears to not conform. From what I've seen, in practice code is written to take this into account, so it can run on Nvidia hardware.
